# Regular expression to exclude number from list

Tags: html, regex

I would like to use regex pattern with `<input`> form element.

In this pattern I would like to put a range of numbers that is not allowed as input.

For instance I would have a list of number `{1,4,10}` and allowed input is **any** number except these.

I've managed to create this regex:

```
[^(1|4|10)]
```

But that also excludes everything contain 0,1 or 4 such as 10.

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Which language are you using? JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If negative lookaheads be allowed, then you can try the following regex:

```
^(?!(?:1|4|10)$)\d+$
```

## Regex101

Comment: Can be shortened to `^(?!(?:1|4|10)$)\d+$`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a character class here (i.e. the [ ]), because the | already means 'this character or that character'.
Instead, use:

```
    ^(1|4|10)$
```

The ^ matches the start of a string, and the $ matches the end of the string, so this will only match 1 (with nothing else), 4 (with nothing else) or 10 (with nothing else).

By the way, to test regex, you can use a online tester such as https://regex101.com/.